# How to know when full data packet is received (QSerialPort)

Tags: qt, serial-port

I use QSerialPort to receive data from serial port of computer. It works well. However, when my device sends 00aabbcc, the readReady() signal is called even when only 00 or 00aa is received.

How can I get a signal, only when all 00aabbcc is received?

Here my code in slot:

```
QByteArray data =  mySerial->readAll();
QString DataAsString = data.toHex();
ui->logArea->append(DataAsString);
```

What I see in the textEdit logArea is:

```
00
aabb 
cc 
00aabb 
cc
```

What i need is

```
00aabbcc
00aabbcc
```

Comment: use [`canReadLine()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html#canReadLine) with [`readLine()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readLine) since the PC usually send an end line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readReady()` fires as soon as you get something in the buffer. If you want to read a fixed number of bytes you need to check for the packet size yourself.

This [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38170282/11476836) should work for you.